C++ passing methods as parameters without lambdas
I've been messing with creating a wrapper using templates to allow the passing of methods as arguments in other methods without having to pepper my calling code in lambda functions based on this reply but have run into an issue.
Namely, the solution compiles when the computing and Answering methods are not part of the class MyClass. However, as soon as I use methods that are part of MyClass i get the following errors.
Intellisense Error: no sutible constrcuctor exists to convert from "void (std::function<void (int)> callback)" to "std::function<void(std::function<void(int)>)>"
Compiller Error: 'MyClass::Computing': non-standard suyntax; use '&' to create pointer to member
I'm betting I'm missing something stupidly simple here.
MyClass.h
class MyClass{
    MyClass();
    
    void A(std::function<void(int)> func);
    void B(int i);
}

MyClass.cpp
MyClass::MyClass(){
    //Erroring Line
    std::function<void(std::function<void(int)>)> question = TheWrapper(Computing);
    question(Answering);
}

void MyClass::Computing(std::function<void(int)> callback){
    //Thinking deep thoughts

    //Answer
    callback(42);
}
void MyClass::Answering(int i){
    //Shrug
}

Wrapper.cpp
template<typename F, typename U>
void TheSystem(F Func, U callback) {
    //Submit request in triplicate
    //Burry in a peat bog
    //Dig up
    
    //Start computation of the meaning of life, the universe, and everything
    Func(callback);
}

std::function<void(std::function<void(int)>)> TheWrapper(const std::function<void(std::function<void(int)>)>& Func) {
    return [Func](std::function<void(int)> callback) { TheSystem(Func, callback); };
}


std::bind is the usual tool for making a std::function out of a method if a lambda is not available. It can be an ugly sucker to work with, which is why you'll usually see lambdas in code and tutorials.

Note your code example has been scrambled in translation, making it harder than necessary to show you how to use std::bind to resolve your current problem. When making an example, make sure it reproduces the problem  and no other problems. Use [mre] for inspiration.

The error message is right: the syntax you used is not standard (though old versions of MS Visual Studio supported it); you must use & to make a pointer to member:
... question = TheWrapper(&MyClass::Computing);

That's about syntax. As for your goal, some comments mentioned std::bind. I have never used it, so can't recommend anything specific, but I do recommend lambdas. Before they were added to the language, you had to trouble yourself with pointer-to-member syntax and placeholders like _1, read awful error messages and pull your hair out. Now you can just use lambdas.

I've tried using &MyClass::Computing but get the same intellisense error, albeit with the class name as part of the signature. The more I dig, the more i feel like I'm trying to jam a square peg into a round hole. The lambda i originally created to do this ended up needing to be nested 3 deep and have multiple function variables passed in which I didn't like. (Oh how I miss .Net's simple use of System.Action as a parameter)

Looks like you had N compilation errors; one was fixed, so now you have N-1 errors.
